# Issue in sending new user notification in GitLab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, delayed-job, gitlab, sidekiq

When I create a new user on GitLab the email is not sent to the new user's email inbox.

I am new to GitLab so don't know  in-depth of it. here goes the log of `"sidekiq.log"`

```
2013-11-06T04:03:55Z 2747 TID--9ygdxi INFO: Booting Sidekiq 2.14.0 using redis://localhost:6379 with options {:namespace=>"resque:gitlab"}

2013-11-06T04:03:55Z 2747 TID--9ygdxi INFO: Running in ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]

2013-11-06T04:03:55Z 2747 TID--9ygdxi INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.

2013-11-06T04:13:08Z 2747 TID--9rl0h4 Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer JID-6ba7a5bad5ed737cf49d9ad9 INFO: start

2013-11-06T04:13:08Z 2747 TID--9rl0h4 Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer JID-6ba7a5bad5ed737cf49d9ad9 INFO: done: 0.339 sec

2013-11-06T05:09:09Z 2747 TID--9rl0h4 Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer JID-312cc90acce9945981cc9cc0 INFO: start

2013-11-06T05:09:09Z 2747 TID--9rl0h4 Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer JID-312cc90acce9945981cc9cc0 INFO: done: 0.114 sec
```

Let me know how to come over this issue? do I need to run any other services?

Comment: As mentioned in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3928 What version of Gitlab are you using? And are you using Sendmail or Postfix for email on your server? Is there nothing odd in the mail logs?

Comment: @VonC Thanks for remaining, I reinstalled the Postfix because i dint selected the internet site earlier while installing. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it by myself, I found what was wrong. I reinstalled postfix and selected internet site its working fine now. In previous install I selected some local option.